# Scala regex pattern match groups different from that using findAllIn

Tags: regex, scala, scala-2.10

I find that the groups extracted by Pattern-matching on regex's in Scala are different from those extracted using findAllIn function.

1) Here is an example of extraction using pattern match -

```
scala> val fullRegex = """(.+?)=(.+?)""".r
fullRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.+?)=(.+?)

scala> val x = """a='b'"""
x: String = a='b'

scala> x match { case fullRegex(l,r) => println( l ); println(r) }
a
'b'
```

2) And here is an example of extraction using the findAllIn function -

```
scala> fullRegex.findAllIn(x).toArray
res4: Array[String] = Array(a=')
```

I was expecting the returned Array using findAllIn to be Array(a, 'b'). **Why is it not so?**

Comment: BTW, I found that the unapplySeq does this kind of extraction perfectly -

     scala> fullRegex.unapplySeq(x)
     res0: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, 'b'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not specified to what extent the second lazy match should go. So after `=` it consumes just one character and stops as it is in lazy mode.

See here.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/10

Change it to `.+?=.+` to get full array

Comment: That does not get me a neat array/list of captured groups. I did this - 

scala> val fullRegex = """(.+?)=(.+)""".r
fullRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.+?)=(.+)

scala> fullRegex.findAllIn(x).toArray
res1: Array[String] = Array(a='b')

Answer (score 0):

In particular, the pattern match's use of `unapplySeq` uses `Matcher.matches`, while `findAllIn` uses `Matcher.find`. `matches` tries to match entire input.

```
scala> import java.util.regex._
import java.util.regex._

scala> val p = Pattern compile ".+?"
p: java.util.regex.Pattern = .+?

scala> val m = p matcher "hello"
m: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.+? region=0,5 lastmatch=]

scala> m.matches
res0: Boolean = true

scala> m.group
res1: String = hello

scala> m.reset
res2: java.util.regex.Matcher = java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=.+? region=0,5 lastmatch=]

scala> m.find
res3: Boolean = true

scala> m.group
res4: String = h

scala>
```